Interpreting AFT or Cox PH model in terms of median
An AFT model has been fit, with a binary sex variable. The coefficient estimate of female was 0.416 (reference level is Male). The interpretation of the coefficient is provided as below.:
"This means being a female subject/patient compared to male changes mean/median survival time by exp(0.416) = 1.516, approximately a 52% increase in mean/median survival time."
For your reference, here's the link to the website that provides this example. The example includes more covariates, but let's ignore them because they are not important. Suppose that the AFT model was fitted on only has the binary sex variable.
Could you please explain why the interpretation is given in median survival time?
Suppose if this was a very simple linear regression y=x * beta+ error, and suppose that estimated beta is 3. Then we are making inference at the expected value of Y, E(Y) = 3*female, meaning, the expected value of Y in female is 3 units higher than male. But expected value is also same as the word mean, so I understand that for linear regression, mean outcome should be used for making inference.
I guess I don't know what it looks like when it comes to survival model. For AFT, would you interpret that females have 3 units higher in expected log transformed survival time? How do you take this to somehow make it mean/median survival time? Also, would your explanation for AFT model apply the same for Cox PH model?
Thank you for your time and help in advance!
